# Not getting response from HTTP Get Method

Tags: go, web-scraping

Implemented an logic in go to fetch the information from given URL,The problem is response of net/http is empty.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    bodyString := string(body)
    fmt.Print(bodyString)
    fmt.Printf("%v %v", body, err)
}
```

Output: its returning empty slice instead of returning HTML content

```
[]byte{} <nil>
```

I'm using Go version 1.14.3.

Comment: I tried it with a few different hosts and it works.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @phonaputer, Ya I agree its working different host but not working for azure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that's working when you set the User-Agent header :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/", nil)
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    bodyString := string(body)
    fmt.Print(bodyString)
}
```

Comment: @Bertrand Martel any reason why it's not working without `User-Agent`?

Comment: @MahmudulHaque most probably the server checks if this header is present in the request